# Asp.net Jquery Array Searching

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Sir,

```
var reservations = [
    { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" },
    { "HotelId": "02", "HotelName": "DPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" },
    { "HotelId": "03", "HotelName": "BPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" },
    { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166910", "Guest Name": "Jomon" },
    { "HotelId": "02", "HotelName": "DPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" }       
];
```

This is my array and i want to search `"HotelId": "01"` , and i want to get this array

```
var newArray = [
    { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" }, 
    { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166910", "Guest Name": "Jomon" }
];
```

Is that possible , can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

```
var reservations = [ { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" }, { "HotelId": "02", "HotelName": "DPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" }, { "HotelId": "03", "HotelName": "BPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" }, { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166910", "Guest Name": "Jomon" }, { "HotelId": "02", "HotelName": "DPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny" }
]

function getByHotelId(id)
{
  return $.grep(reservations,function(d,i){
    return d.HotelId==id
  });
}
var newArray =getByHotelId('01');
alert(JSON.stringify(newArray ));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/qwc1kbtk/1/)